# Can Moderators be replaced / removed / demoted?

Tags: discussion

If a moderators isn't very active, or doesn't contribute as expected, can they be replaced/removed/demoted?

Comment: Theoretically, [they can](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151606).